# Is it valid to replace DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider and manipulate the returned ModelMetadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, metadata

We are currently building a mid-sized intranet application using MVC3. One requirement is the possibility to change and translate field names and labels on the fly. We are currently using extended versions of `ViewPage`, `ViewMasterPage` and `ViewUserControl` enriched by an translation helper injected by spring.net to achieve this requirement.

This solution solves all requirements except MVC features that rely on `ModelMetadata` (e.g. `LabelFor`). My first thought was that there should be an extension point to replace the current implementation. Luckily the MVC team build `ModelMetadataProviders` in a way that I can inject a custom translation aware `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`.

```
protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata( IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName )
{
  // Call the base method and obtain a metadata object.
  var metadata = base.CreateMetadata( attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName );

  if( containerType != null )
  {
    // Obtain informations to query the translator.
    var objectName = containerType.FullName;
    var displayName = metadata.GetDisplayName();

    // Query the translator.
    var translatedDisplayName = Translator.Translate( objectName, displayName );

    // Update the metadata.
    metadata.DisplayName = translatedDisplayName;
  }

  return metadata;
}
```

I'm using the `containerType` and `GetDisplayName()` as key to obtain a translation from a translation contributor (that uses caching, does not degrade performance), then calling base and change the returned `ModelMetadata` by updating the `DisplayName` property before returning it.

What makes me unconfident about this solution is that I can't predict what side effects I have to expect? Or if there is a better, proper solution?

Comment: According to a [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx) by Phil Haack and the related bitbucket project this seams to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the valid usage.

Make sure you derive from `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` as you do to reuse all the features it provides.

You can also handle more custom attributes here - you can decorate your model with your own custom attributes and then update `ModelMetadata` based on them.